# How to center li tags list

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying list of tags in a website. This is how it is displayed now

[image]

[*I've created a JSFiddle, Please check.*](http://jsfiddle.net/hxbB9/3/)

Now the tags are aligned left, I need to align tags to centre. Tried adding `text-align: center;` to `.tags` class but it does not center the tags.

This is my HTML & CSS code

**HTML**

```
<div class="tags">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">tag 0000000</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tag 1111111111111</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.tags
{
    display:table;
}

.tags li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.tags ul a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #F2F0F0;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

I need to display tags as many as fit in to a row, but the contents of the row must be aligned center.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 Actually not one below another, there I need to display as many as fit in to a row, but the contents of the row must aligned center.

Comment: Can't you just add `text-align:center;` or `margin:0 auto;width:xxx;` to `.tags ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hxbB9/18/
another alternative solutiont that dosnt require setting a width on your `.tags` div

```
.tags
{

}

.tags li
{ 
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.tags ul a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #F2F0F0;
    margin: 2px;
}

.tags ul
{
    text-align:center;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
.tags ul
{
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.tags ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tags ul a
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #F2F0F0;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hxbB9/6/

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I guess I haven't explained my requirement clearly, now I've updated the question. However thanks for the answer.